# Subtracting groupwise means from columns using either plyr or matrix algebra

Tags: r, linear-algebra, plyr, mean

I'm trying to write some parallelizable code (exploting `plyr` and `doMC`) to calculate and subtract groupwise means from columns of a data frame.  I'm having a hard time getting the `plyr` syntax correct.

Here is the script with a working for-loop:

```
data = data.frame(x = rnorm(100),y = rnorm(100),ID = round(runif(100)*10))
data = data[with(data,order(ID)),]
dm = matrix(rep(NA,nrow(data)*(ncol(data)-1)),nrow(data),(ncol(data)-1))

for (i in 1:(ncol(data)-1)){
    m = summaryBy(data[,i]~ID,data=data,fun=mean)
    d = data.frame(data[,i],ID=data$ID)
    a = merge(d,m,by="ID")
    dm[,i] = a[,2]-a[,3]
    }
```

But I try to break it by the column names of data using ddply, and it gives me an error message.  Here is my non-working code:

```
dmf = function(i){
    m = summaryBy(data[,i]~ID,data=data,fun=mean)
    d = data.frame(data[,i],ID=data$ID)
    a = merge(d,m,by="ID")
    dm = a[,2]-a[,3]
    as.data.frame(dm)
    }

dm = ddply(.data=data,.fun = dmf,.variables = colnames(data))

>Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Anybody have a solution for this?

Alternatively, if this is doable with matrices, I'd greatly appreciate that sort of solution from someone with better matrix intuition than me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take full advantage of `plyr`, I would combine `colwise` and the base function `scale`. Also, if needed, let `ddply` handle the parallelization at the highest level:

```
dm <- ddply(data, "ID", colwise(scale, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE),
            .parallel = TRUE)
```